# How to use an MySQL association table to return categories not currently assigned to an entry

Tags: mysql

I have a database of product entries.  Each product entry can be associated with multiple categories.  I have created an association table to create these associations.  What I am trying to do is create a MySQL query that will return all categories that are not currently assigned to the entry.

So if an entry is a Pool Table and it is already assigned to the Gaming category, I want to create a query that will return all categories except Gaming.

Below are table structure for my database.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Entry Table:**

```
+--------------+------------------+
| Field        | Type             |
+--------------+------------------+
| eid          | int(10) unsigned |
| entry_name   | varchar(50)      |
+--------------+------------------+
```

**Category Table:**

```
+----------------+------------------------+
| Field          | Type                   |
+----------------+------------------------+
| cid            | smallint(11) unsigned  |
| cat_name       | varchar(30)            |
+----------------+------------------------+
```

**Association Table:**

```
+-------+-----------------------+
| Field | Type                  |
+-------+-----------------------+
| eid   | int(10) unsigned      |
| cid   | smallint(11) unsigned |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Take a look at left join and null ;)

Comment: Thanks.  Will do some research.  Still a MySQL beginner :)

Comment: I am just not getting this.  Anyone else able to provide some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with the tip from nick rulez.

This query returns the categories that have not been assigned to a particular entry.  In this example, the entry id is 493:

```
select c.* from category c left join Association a on a.pid = c.pid and a.eid = '493' where a.eid is NULL
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.cid, c.cat_name
FROM Category c
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Association a
  where a.cid = c.cid
)
```

Comment: Thanks Max.  That is not quite what I was looking for. Your statement will return all categories that have not been associated with anything yet. I just want to return all categories that have not already been assigned to that particular entry.